# How to get the uninstaller name in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a project with different variants , which all install to the same location e.g. `C:\ABC\`. Here the uninstallers are named unins000, unins001.. and so on. I have searched on net to changed the uninstaller names, and there is no inherent way to change the uninstaller name.

I have a workaround , by which I use the `[Run]` section to rename `unins000.exe` to the name of my choice. This works great on project folders when there will be only one uninstaller. However, in my case, the uninstaller name is not known to me.

Can someone suggest me a way to get the uninstaller name ? I will put the name accordingly in my code.

Please don't suggest me to look for timestamp. That will not be an acceptable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to rename the uninstaller in the first place?

Comment: I explained it already. There are multiple uninstallers in one folder. This is confusing to users when they want to uninstall only one variant.

Comment: The user should not uninstall the application by going to installation folder and executing the uninstaller. The user should go to Control Panel and select the application by its name.

Comment: See also [Change the default name of an Inno-Setup uninstaller to avoid naming conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18625533/850848).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added the code below I used to achieve I wanted. Basically, what I am doing now is I create a seperate folder for each variant, where I store the individual uninstaller ( as I was not able to get the uninstaller which I will need to rename ) .

The project structure is now

`C:\ABC\Uninst\<Variant-1>\<variant1-uninstaller>`
`C:\ABC\Uninst\<Variant-2>\<variant2-uninstaller>`

Add the `[Run]` section , this will change the uninstaller name to whatever is required. Also, registry entry in HKLM will be modified so that shortcuts and Control panel can uninstall the programs without any issues.

```
 `[Run]

  ;First rename the uninstaller files, then modify in registry
  ; /C : run CMD, execute command, then close the CMD.exe
  Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/C ren ""{app}\Uninst\unins000.exe"" ""Uninstall_{#ApplicationName}.exe"""; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated

 Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/C ren ""{app}\Uninst\unins000.dat"" ""Uninstall_{#ApplicationName}.dat"""; Flags:  RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated

 ; REG ADD [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/t DataType] [/S Separator] [/d Data] [/f]
 ; /F : Force overwrite
 Filename: REG; Parameters: "ADD ""HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#AppNameInReg}_is1"" /V ""UninstallString"" /T ""REG_SZ"" /D ""\""{app}\Uninst\Uninstall_{#ApplicationName}.exe"""" /F"; StatusMsg: Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated

 Filename: REG; Parameters: "ADD ""HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#AppNameInReg}_is1"" /V ""QuietUninstallString"" /T ""REG_SZ"" /D ""\""{app}\Uninst\Uninstall_{#ApplicationName}.exe /SILENT"""" /F"; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
```

Add the following line in `[Setup]` section
    `UninstallFilesDir={app}\Uninst\` 
This will create `unins000.exe` in `Uninst` folder.

Please note that I have solved my issue. I posted my code for any one who want to do similiar things.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the uninstaller is `unins000.exe`. Plus you will have problems when uninstalling after upgrade. Do not do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Inno Setup does not offer any way to let you name (or rename) the uninstaller.

Also note that when you rename the uninstaller manually (like you are doing), you break the reference to the uninstaller in the *Add or remote application* in Control Panel. Do not do that.

Another problem is that when you upgrade later, the new installer won't find logs of the previous installer and won't be able to merge them. Consequently a future uninstallation won't completely remove the application.
See the [Appending to Existing Uninstall Logs](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=appendnotes) in Inno Setup documentation.

The user should not uninstall the application by going to installation folder and executing the uninstaller. The user should go to Control Panel and select the application by its name.

---

Anyway, the uninstallers are numbered sequentially, so you can pick the uninstaller with the highest number.

Comment: I will add the code I have used to achieve renaming uninstallers. Using that, Add or Remove programs from Control Panel works okay. I tested it.